# Fody.PropertyChanged doesn't fire on inherited Property

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged, fody, fody-propertychanged

I have a `Control` which inherits from `NumericUpDown` in WinForms.

I want to handle changes to the `DecimalPlaces`-Property of `NumericUpDown`, therefore I have both tried declaring a

```
void OnDecimalPlacesChanged()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Moeeep");
}
```

and also manually subscribing the `PropertyChanged`-`event` in the ctor manually. It seems to just not fire when I update `DecimalPlaces` and I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Sure you didn't miss the `override` on `void OnDecimalPlacesChanged()`?

Comment: There is no method to override. This is a convention by Fody.PropertyChanged. How ever, as I said the event doen't fire, no matter what way I am subscribing

Comment: So you say it should auto-wire the event?

Comment: Thais what ist is weiten for. Google fody.propertychanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Control` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, only your class does. Because of that, the `Control` doesn't raise any event when the `DecimalPlaces` changes. No framework can inject that into their code.

For now, the best thing you have is to override the `UpdateEditText` method. It is called when the `DecimalPlaces` property changes. Note that this is of course not the only reason the method is called, so you might have a problem there...

Comment: Something like https://harmony.pardeike.net/articles/patching.html could actually inject that into the base class